# Is anyone having difficulty with getting ZBar to work in their iOS8 / Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, zbar-sdk

Has Anyone else experienced this issue with ZBar? My app stopped detecting bar codes when I migrated my project to XCode 6 / iOS8 and I am using ZBar 1.3 code.  No error message is thrown.  App just stopped detecting bar codes.  I recompiled my ZBar project for arm64, armv7 & armv7s and merged the simulator and iphone libzbar.a file into one and reinserted into my project.  Still not able to scan using ZBar in my app and I noticed there are about 245 warnings in the ZBar code that arise from deprecation of functions in iOS6 and iOS7 amongst other things.  I also noticed another developers app that uses ZBar has stopped working when I upgraded my phone to iOS8 as well.  BTW: It looks like the ZBar code hasn't been updated since 2012 in Mercurial so, I may just write my own bar code scanning routine using the AVFoundation framework.

Comment: Same issue i faced.. If you found any solution or alternative.. please post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We decided to abandon ZBar and just write our own bar code scanning routine using the Avfoundation framework.  We really like ZBar but, the source hasn't been touched in 2 years and there around many deprecations that need to be fixed and the Avfoundation framework is very straight forward and easy to use for bar code scanning.  Check out this link to a simple tutorial to get started (http://www.appcoda.com/qr-code-ios-programming-tutorial/).